# "Error(2,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" and "Error(3,86): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here"

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a `product` table and `product_Backup` table;

```
create trigger ins after insert 
on products for each row 
begin
   insert into
      products_backup(productid, description, productname, quantity, price, purchasedate) 
   values
      (
         new.productid, new.description, new.productname, new.quantity, new.price, new.purchasedate
      );
end;
```

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Seems you are using Oracle? But you have tagged SQL Server?

Comment: Also note the code formatting option in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot colon character (`:`) before `new` (what you should have used is `:new`)

```
create trigger ins after insert on products
    for each row
   begin
   insert into products_backup(productid,description,productname,quantity,price,purchasedate)
   values (:new.productid, :new.description,:new.productname,:new.quantity,:new.price,:new.purchasedate);
   end;
```

Comment: I tried this but was still getting errors like new and old can't be used in table level trigger